# How do I create a dictionary from given txt file?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a text file consisting of usernames and a passwords, separated by a comma that I need to convert into a dictionary like this:

```
userData = [{'username': 'something@test.com', 'password': 'test123'},
            {'username': 'somethingelse@test.com', 'password': 'test1234'},
            {'username': 'somethingmore@test.com', 'password': 'test123'},
            ]
```

The file looks like this:

```
something@test.com,test123
somethingelse@test.com,test1234
somethingmore@test.com,test123
```

I tried the following, but it only returns the last line of the text file, so I assume the dictionary is overwritten for each line.

```
file = open('username.txt', 'r')
userData = {}
userData['username'] = ''
userData['password'] = ''

for line in file:
   x = line.split(',')
   un = x[0]
   pw = x[1]
   userData['username']=un
   userData['password']=pw
```

What can I do to get the correct output?

Comment: Yes, it's overwritten. The output you want is a list of dictionaries - where's your list? Why not create the dictionaries *inside* the loop?

Comment: I _really_ hope you aren't storing passwords for something important in plaintext.

Comment: The problem is that you want a *list of dictionaries*. `userData` is **not** a dictionary...

Comment: Can't you store it as a dictionary that contains the email address as key and password as value. It would make things easier.

Comment: If you're reading CSV use the [**`csv`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module. There's a class named [**`DictReader`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) to convert the rows into dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

You want a list of dictionaries, but you only create a dictionary that it's modified each time in for loop. You have to create another dictionary for each line and store it in list.
Try this:

```
file = open('username.txt', 'r')
userDataList = []

for line in file:
   x = line.split(',')
   userData = {}
   userData['username'] = x[0]
   userData['password'] = x[1]
   userDataList.append(userData)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
file = open('username.txt', 'r')
userData = {}

for line in file:
   x = line.split(',')
   userData[x[0]] = x[1]
```

In your original code you're not actually altering the dictionary, just one username and password.

EDIT: I misread the question.  Mine stores each username as a key and each password as the value.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) in the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module:

```
import csv

with open('usernames.txt') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile,
                            fieldnames=['username', 'password'])
    users = list(reader)
```

For example:

```
>>> import csv
>>> import pprint
>>> from StringIO import StringIO

>>> content = """something@test.com,test123
... somethingelse@test.com,test1234
... somethingmore@test.com,test123"""

>>> usernames = StringIO(content)
>>> pprint(list(csv.DictReader(usernames,
...                            fieldnames=['username', 'password'])))
[OrderedDict([('username', 'something@test.com'), ('password', 'test123')]),
 OrderedDict([('username', 'somethingelse@test.com'),
              ('password', 'test1234')]),
 OrderedDict([('username', 'somethingmore@test.com'), ('password', 'test123')])]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you actually want to do is create a list of dictionary objects. I'd use the `csv` module to read the data, since the content of the file appears to be that of Character Separated Values.

```
import csv
import sys

def open_csv(filename, mode='r'):
    """Open a csv file in proper mode depending on Python verion."""
    return(open(filename, mode=mode+'b') if sys.version_info[0] == 2 else
           open(filename, mode=mode, newline=''))

def read_data(filename, fieldnames):
    with open_csv(filename, mode='r') as file:
        for row in csv.DictReader(file, fieldnames=fieldnames):
            yield row

fieldnames = 'username password'.split()
user_data = [row for row in read_data('username.txt', fieldnames)]

print(user_data)
```

Output:

`[{'username': 'something@test.com', 'password': 'test123'}, 
  {'username': 'somethingelse@test.com', 'password': 'test1234'}, 
  {'username': 'somethingmore@test.com', 'password': 'test123'}]`